# Constructor: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

Tags: angular, api, syntax-error

I'm new to Angular. Forgive my beginner mistakes.

I have a DataService (WatsonService) and a component. The DataService get data from the IBM Watson Cloud over the BearerAuthenticator. I have a return statement `return (JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2));` and I want to process the return in my component.

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BearerTokenAuthenticator} from 'ibm-cloud-sdk-core';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WatsonService {

public getMatchings(){

const DiscoveryV2 = require('ibm-watson/discovery/v2');
const discovery = new DiscoveryV2({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  authenticator: new BearerTokenAuthenticator({ bearerToken: 'ABCDEF' }),
  url: 'https://Watson.api',
  version: '2019-11-29',
  disableSslVerification: true

});

discovery.query({
  projectId: '12345',
  collectionId: '54321',
  query: 'typ::Antwort'
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2));
  return (JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2));

})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);

});
console.log();
}
}
```

**Component**

```
import { WatsonService } from './../_service/data.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-list',
  templateUrl: './page-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-list.component.sass'],
  providers:  [WatsonService]
})
export class PageListComponent implements OnInit {

  public matchShow: boolean;
  public matchShowMore: boolean;
  public $summaryValues = [];

  constructor(private watsonService: WatsonService) {
    this.matchShow = true;
    this.matchShowMore = true;
    this.$summaryValues = this.watsonService.getMatchings();

  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

I get an error with `this.$summaryValues`. "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'any[]'." I dont understand what that means. Whats wrong? Could somebody tell me how do I assign it to get my data from the API (DataService)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Probably you need to return an array from `getMatchings()` function. Currently it's returning `undefined`.

Comment: There's no `return` statement in `getMatchings()`, so nothing (`undefined`) will be returned (ie, the method's return type is `void`). The `return` inside the `then(...)` only returns the lambda function inside of it, not the whole method. You need to return the promise (`discovery.query...`). However, since it's a promise, you need to make the method `async` and await the result

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can't use require in angular
you should import like this:
import * as DiscoveryV2 from 'ibm-watson/discovery';
second you should return promise its self and call method and set your summaryvalues in then clause in the constructor

Comment: This is the official implementation example from IBM and it works with "require". I get some data in my log.